# Does re-posting a question after it's been deleted still make it show up under "first questions"?

Tags: support, review

A common spam tactic is to post "bait" questions and answer them yourself (or have them answered by sock puppets). For example, post a question "How to transfer iPhone movies to PC?" and have it answered by somebody promoting a crappy $29 software. Or [this one here](https://superuser.com/questions/353553/how-can-i-get-an-oval-screenshot-on-a-mac). <sub>(SU mods only, see the deleted comments)</sub>

Anyway, such a question would initially show up under `first questions` in the review pages. Let's hope such a question is deleted (for obvious reasons).

When the same user posts a similar question again, **does it show up under `first questions`**?

Comment: An *oval screenshot?*  Losers.

Comment: All the stuff about spam and reposting the same question seem irrelevant -- is your question just "does a user's question show up under 'first questions' if they have other deleted questions?"?

Comment: @Michael Yes. That's why I even emphasized it. However I don't think it's irrelevant, as it's an argument for the importance of being able to see such a question – if that's not already the case yet.

Comment: I'm tempted to create a second sockpuppet account just to test this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes they show up**. In particular we show:

1. The first question by any user with rep under 100
2. All the questions by any users with rep under 10 (who are not suspended)

We exclude:

1. Closed questions
2. Deleted questions
3. Questions you reviewed
4. Questions 2 of your peers reviewed

phew ... so many rules ...